# Executing SQL powershell query in VBscript

Tags: sql, vbscript

I am executing sql query in vbscript, query is as follow it gives information about drives available for each server

VBScript code (slightly restructured):

```
Strquery = "DECLARE @Totaldbspacegb BIGINT;" & _
  "DECLARE @Totaldriveusedspacegb INT;" & _
  "DECLARE @Totaldrivefreespacegb INT;" & _
  "DECLARE @Svrname VARCHAR(255);" & _
  "DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(400);" & _
  "DECLARE @Forcast6monthsgb NUMERIC(38, 6);" & _
  "DECLARE @Forcast12monthsgb NUMERIC(38, 6);"
Strquery = Strquery & "; DECLARE @Avggrowthingb NUMERIC(38, 6);" & _
  "CREATE TABLE #Temp1(Yer INT NULL, Mnth INT NULL," & _
    "Sumdbinmb NUMERIC(38, 6)NULL, Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL);" & _
  "CREATE TABLE #Temp4(Totaldriveusedspacegb INT, Totaldrivefreespacegb INT);" 
Strquery = Strquery & "; SELECT @Totaldbspacegb = SUM(Size) FROM Sys.Master_Files"
Strquery = Strquery & "; SELECT @Totaldbspacegb = @Totaldbspacegb * 8. / 1024.0 / 1024"
Strquery = Strquery & "; SET @Svrname = '" & Strserver & "';"
Sql = " Powershell.Exe - C ""Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume -Filter ''DriveType = 3''| select name,label,capacity,freespace | foreach{$_.name+''!''+$_.label+''|''+$_.capacity/1048576+''%''+$_.freespace/1048576+''*''}""" 
Strquery = Strquery & "CREATE TABLE #Output(Line VARCHAR(255)); INSERT INTO #Output"
Strquery = Strquery & "; EXEC Xp_Cmdshell '" & sql & "';"
Strquery = Strquery & "; SELECT * FROM #Output;"
```

Resulting (formatted) SQL code:

```
DECLARE @Totaldbspacegb BIGINT;
DECLARE @Totaldriveusedspacegb INT;
DECLARE @Totaldrivefreespacegb INT;
DECLARE @Svrname VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(400);
DECLARE @Forcast6monthsgb NUMERIC(38, 6);
DECLARE @Forcast12monthsgb NUMERIC(38, 6);
;
DECLARE @Avggrowthingb NUMERIC(38, 6);
CREATE TABLE #Temp1(Yer INT NULL,
                    Mnth INT NULL,
                    Sumdbinmb NUMERIC(38, 6)NULL,
                    Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
                   );
CREATE TABLE #Temp4(Totaldriveusedspacegb INT,
                    Totaldrivefreespacegb INT
                   );
;
SELECT @Totaldbspacegb = SUM(Size)
  FROM Sys.Master_Files;
SELECT @Totaldbspacegb = @Totaldbspacegb * 8. / 1024.0 / 1024;
SET @Svrname = '...';
CREATE TABLE #Output(Line VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO #Output;
EXEC Xp_Cmdshell 'Powershell.Exe - C "Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume -Filter ''DriveType = 3''| select name,label,capacity,freespace | foreach{$_.name+''!''+$_.label+''|''+$_.capacity/1048576+''%''+$_.freespace/1048576+''*''}"';
;
SELECT *
  FROM #Output;
```

I am executing this query it gave me output while running from management studio while running in .vbs file it give me record count as null, how to find whether query is executing sucessfully.
is it due to powershell command it is not running in vbscript.

Please help

Comment: The code snippet you posted just defines a bunch of variables without *doing* anything. Please add the code that's supposed to do something with those variables.

Comment: this is query which i execute through .vbs file

Comment: cmd.commandtext=strquery rs=cmd.execute when iam checking for EOF its giving me record count as empty while not rs.eof msgbox("has records") wend

Comment: Did you check if both `.EOF` *and* `.BOF` are `True`? Only then the recordset is empty. Otherwise issue `rs.MoveFirst` before starting the loop. What is the result of `TypeName(rs)`? And how do you establish the database connection? Did you check if that connection works at all?

Comment: yes i checked all, i place another query it works fine. is this due to powershell script iam running in query..?

Comment: Perhaps a typo in your PowerShell command? I think `Powershell.Exe - C "..."` should actually be `Powershell.Exe -C "..."` (no space between `-` and `C`).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to update the temporary table `#Output` with the result of the PowerShell command? If so, I don't think your instructions will do what you want.

```
INSERT INTO #Output;
EXEC Xp_Cmdshell 'Powershell.Exe -C "..."';
SELECT *
  FROM #Output;
```

`INSERT INTO #Output;` is not a valid statement, and you don't do anything with the output of the PowerShell command.